# JAR library references with identical file names but different contents were found

Tags: xamarin.android

JAR library references with identical file names but different contents were found: androidx.annotation.annotation.jar androids.collection.collection.jar, androidx.lifecycle.lifecycle-common.jar, androidx.arch.core.core-common.jar. Please remove any conflicting libraries from EmbeddedJar, Inputlar and AndroidJavalibrary.

This issue is coming recently and is this something related with GPS as we are not able to read co-ordinates

Comment: Hi @chirag, Were you able to find the solution for this?